# Estimate based on data

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics

I have a set of data containing the price of stores where

```
y = 100.4,560.2,432.1,600.2,231.5,706.6
```

and I want to **calculate the estimate** of the **average price** of stores which is based on the data given above but I'm not quite sure of the term estimate, hence i attempted

```
e = 100.4 + 560.2 + 432.1 + 600.2 + 231.5 + 706.6 /6
  = 438.5
```

Would calculating the mean of the data set justify the term of estimate?

Comment: yes, if there other things are attached.

Comment: The definition of the average e, is wrong.  Notice that 1 + 3 / 2 = 2.5.